# File from assets folder doesn't show on android - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an html file in the assets/documents folder.

And I have to display it in a webview as follows:

```
 <WebView source={require('../assets/documents/document.html')} style={{flex:1}} />
```

I am displaying it from my screens folder which is at the same level as assets :

```
 assets
     documents
        document.html
 screens
    myScreen.js
```

On iPhone, this displays fine. But on Android, I get a blank page and the file doesn't load.
I am using react-native.

Does the path change when it is not on development mode? How do I access it best?
Thanks.

Comment: The path does change once you move to production build. Try checking on the minified build code.